# Stacked Plot To Represent Genders For An Age Group From CSV containing Identifier , Age and Gender On Python / Pandas/ Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a csv data with age, gender(Men,Women) and identifier. I grouped age and gender of individuals by count of identifier on pandas with

```
counts = df.groupby(['Age','Gender']).count()
print counts
```

and the result looked something like this :

```
Age Gender      Id_count       
15  W                 1
17  M                 1
19  M                 2
20  M                 6
    W                 1
21  M                 3
    W                 1
23  M                 4
    W                 3
24  M                 8
    W                 3
25  M                 9
26  M                 6
    W                 1
27  M                 3
    W                 1
28  M                 9
    W                 2
29  M                 5
    W                 1
30  M                 3
31  M                 9
    W                 1 ..
```

Unique ages on my dataset are from age 15 to 90. I now want to do an age group analysis with a stacked plot at the end.For that , i want to lets say range the ages into certain age group (10-20,21-30,31-40 and so on) and plot sum of identifier on each age group , showing sum on the top of the bar and my aim is to get two different colors for stacked bar representing men and women according to their proportion of id_count. To implement this : i created a dictionary where i gave range as shown below..

```
df['ids_counted']= np.round(df['Age'])
categories_dict = { 15 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    16 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    17 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    18 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    19 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    20 : 'Between 10 and 20',
                    21 : 'Between 21 and 30',
                    22 : 'Between 21 and 30',..
                    90 : 'Between 81 and 90',}
```

Then I created this dataframe.

```
df['category'] = df['id_counted'].map(categories_dict)
count2 = df.groupby(['category','Age','Gender','Id_Count']).count()
total= count2.sum(level= 0)
print total
```

now i have successfully counted the total of identifier on each age group. It looked something like this :

```
Between 10 and 20                           11
Between 21 and 30                           62
Between 31 and 40                           82
Between 41 and 50                          120
Between 51 and 60                          125
Between 61 and 70                          141
Between 71 and 80                          192
Between 81 and 90                           38
```

But i lost my way here because i wanted to plot gender too. lets take age between 10 and 20 . Total 11 should have been on the top of my bar and portion 9 men and 2 women should have been plotted on a stacked bar. I thought about another approach because i think this way to approach won't get me to my result. I generated a grouped dataframe with the counts of each M and F per age, then calculated the total number of individual per age group.

```
totals = counts.sum(level=0)
```

Now to plot :

```
plt.bar(ages, counts['M'], bottom=None, color='blue', label='M')
plt.bar(ages, counts['W'], bottom=counts['M'], color='red', label='W')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Age Group')
plt.ylabel('Occurences Of Identifiers')
plt.title('ttl',fontsize=20)


for age,tot in zip(ages,totals.values.flatten()):
    plt.annotate('{:d}'.format(tot), xy=(age+0.39, tot), xytext=(0,1), textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
plt.save()
plt.close()
```

and got this plot which turned out to be okay [image] but it is for individual age and my target is to generate same plot for age group on my dictionary. I would be very grateful if anyone would suggest me or give me an idea to obtain my aimed result. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning age groups is easier using [`np.digitize`](http://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html).

```
n = 100
age = np.random.randint(15, 91, size=n)
gender = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Age', age), ('Gender', gender)])
bins = np.arange(1, 10) * 10
df['category'] = np.digitize(df.Age, bins, right=True)
print(df.head())

   Age  Gender  category
0   22       1         2
1   54       0         5
2   85       1         8
3   77       0         7
4   86       1         8
```

Now count grouping by category and gender, then unstack the result to have gender as columns.

```
counts = df.groupby(['category', 'Gender']).Age.count().unstack()
print(counts)

Gender     0  1
category       
1          2  7
2          7  5
3          6  4
4         11  9
5          5  8
6          2  4
7         10  7
8          6  7
```

Plotting is now a breeze.

```
counts.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much goyo .

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my code at last :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/cocktail_ids_age_gender.csv')
df.values


bins = np.arange(10, 100, 10)

df['category'] = np.digitize(df.Age, bins, right=True)

counts = df.groupby(['category', 'Gender']).Age.count().unstack()
print(counts)

ax = counts.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False, colormap = 'Paired')

for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=0).astype(np.int64), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(2, 10), textcoords='offset points')

plt.xlabel ('Age Group')
plt.ylabel ('Co-Occurences ')
plt.title('Comparison Of Occurences  In An Age Group',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image] And i decided to leave it stacked anyways because it made analysis easier. Everything turned out well , thanks to goyo. But the only thing that is again bothering me is my x-axis. Instead of showing 1 , 2 , 3 , 4.. i wanted to show 10-20,20-30 and so on. I am not grasping how i could do that. Can anyone help me. Thank you

Comment: You can [set the tick labels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.‌​axes.Axes.set_xtickl‌​abels) in the plot or the index of the DataFrame to the values you want.